# How to associate an email address with Yammer Groups

Tags: yammer

Can you find out if we can associate an email address with Yammer Groups? For example, we have an ITRMS Yammer group and when I'm sending an e-mail to consultants via Exchange, it would be nice to be able to just copy an e-mail address that will post to a Yammer group as opposed to copying it over to Yammer (saves a few steps). When I click on the "members" or "info" link for Yammer groups, it just hangs so not sure if this would be available if that function worked.

Answer (score 1):

Every group has an email address associated with it. The `mailto` link is contained in the *Post to this group by email* link.

[image]